# WooCommerce: How do I add a product thumbnail image to added to cart message?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using this snippet below to slightly modify Woocommerce's added to cart message. It redirects to the cart page from product pages. I'd like to add the product's thumbnail image to that Woocommerce message notification to show it clearer to the customer what has been added to the cart. Any solutions? I've tried a bunch of different ways, but no success.

```
function ace_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) {

$count = 0;
$titles = array();
foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
    $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) );
    $count += $qty;
}

$titles     = array_filter( $titles );
$added_text = sprintf( _n(
    '%s has been added to your cart.', // Singular
    '%s are added to your cart.', // Plural
    $count, // Number of products added
    'woocommerce' // Textdomain
), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );
$message    = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ), esc_html__( 'Proceed to checkout', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );

return $message;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wc_add_to_cart_message` action hook. try the below code.

```
function add_product_image_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $product_id ){

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $product_id ) ):
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    endif;

    $message = sprintf( '<img src="'.$image[0].'" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;float: left;margin-right: 10px;" />%s', $message );   
    
    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'add_product_image_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
```

**Tested and Works**

[image]